# Save an Object into User Defaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am not able to save the list of viewControllers in my user defaults, its getting crashed at this `userDefault.set(vcList, forKey: "vcList")`.

The error log says:

> *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct viewControllerList {
        var vc1 = ViewController()
        var vc2 = LoginViewController()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vcList = viewControllerList()
        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefault.set(vcList, forKey: "vcList")
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: both the scenarios are different

Comment: If you are trying to save the state of viewController to restore the app state, then you are doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **UserDefaults** class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as **`floats, doubles, integers, Boolean values, and URLs`**.

A **default** object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or for collections, a combination of instances of) **`NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary`**. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of **`NSData`**.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
//MARK:- Save viewController in UserDefault
    func saveInDefaults(_ viewController : UIViewController) -> Void{
        do {
            let encodeData  = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodeData, forKey: "vcList")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

*And Call function from `viewDidLoad`*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vcList = viewControllerList()
        self.saveInDefaults(vcList)
    }
```